# Angularjs Service Promice Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build simple service in angularjs. The response of service is getting undefined in controller. Below is my code:

Service:

```
yourMarketApp.factory('User',function($http){

    return {
        getUserCount: function(){
            var count;
            $http.get('/Ecomm-Java-Backend/test').success(function(result) {
                console.log("Count is "+result);
                console.log(result);
                count =result;
                return count;
            })


        }
    }

});
```

Controller:

```
yourMarketApp.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope,User){

    $scope.count =0;
    var temp =User.getUserCount();
     User.getUserCount().then(function(data){
         $scope.count=data;
         console.log("Count is From ctrl "+$scope.count);
    });

});
```

Here console.log in service is giving desired result. But,in controller the error reads: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". One observation is code is not breaking at var temp line, so service is injected nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from `$http.get` in `getUserCount`:

```
return {
    getUserCount: function(){
        var count;
        return $http.get('/Ecomm-Java-Backend/test').success(function(result) {
            console.log("Count is "+result);
            console.log(result);
            count =result;
            return count;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks :)